# Issues with db in pyramid + Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, pylons

I am creating a simple app in pyramid . While inserting data i am getting db locked error.

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked [SQL: 'INSERT INTO users (name, email, number) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('test', 't@t.com', '123654')]

But first time it inserts the data correctly and on 2nd time it gives this error.

Any idea why this is happening second time ?

Here is my code :

```
name = request.params['name']
email = request.params['email']
no = request.params['number']
DBSession.add(User(name, email, no))

# Get the new ID and redirect
users = DBSession.query(User).all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite can only handle 1 concurrent transaction.

Have you tried `commit()`before performing a `query()` then `close()` to end the session?

```
name = request.params['name']
email = request.params['email']
no = request.params['number']
DBSession.add(User(name, email, no))

# Commit the transaction if complete
DBSession.commit()

# Get the new ID and redirect
users = DBSession.query(User).all()

# Close the session
DBSession.close()
```

Comment: One edit , It would be `transaction.commit()` not  `DBSession.commit()` . Also first `import transaction`